# How to vertically center elements of body without centering navbar

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox

So I have a page with a `navbar` and a bunch of content. The outline of the code is as follows:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<!-- Various navbar links here -->
</div>

<div class="container">
<!-- Some content here -->
</div>
```

What I want is for the `container` to be centered in the `body`, but keep the `navbar` at the top.

The above code aligns both `navbar` and `container` in the center. How can I vertically center `container` in `body` and keep `navbar` from being centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```css
html, body {height: 100%} /* mandatory */
body {margin: 0} /* mandatory */

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 150px); /* moved down by 50% of the screen height - half of the container's height - navbar's height */
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: Khaki;
}

.container {
  width: 1200px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: Lavender;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
<!-- Various navbar links here -->
</div>

<div class="container">
<!-- Some content here -->
</div>
```

The `body` *element* should become *flex-container* with `flex-direction: column`, so that it stacks its *items* *vertically*. Since you only want to `center` the `.container` *div*, you give the `.navbar` an `absolute` `position` and move it exactly above it with the `top` *property* and appropriate *value*, calculated with the *CSS* `calc()` *function*.

Answer (score 0):

You can give .container a fixed width:

```
.container {

max-width: 860px;
margin-right: auto;
margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make body a column `flex` container and use `margin` for `.navbar` and `.container` instead `justify-content` and `align-items` from the flex parent.

Basic code needed :

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.navbar {
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">navbar
</div>

<div class="container">
  container
</div>
```

*(min-)*`width` and *(min-)*`height` can be applied to your boxes to fit your needs.